# Global variable undefined in JavaScript when using fileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am writing a utility that will (should) allow the user to attach a text document ('test.txt') and store the content of that file into the global variable `output`. What I don't understand (I've gotta be missing something here) is that within the below code (`alert(output + " | " + test);`) returns `output` as undefined but `test` as "Hello"

It's like the `fileReader` disposes of everything once it finishes so `output` gets set back to undefined. However, by setting the innerText of a `div` element (output), it prints the data to the page just fine if everything is within the `fileReader.onload` function. If it's outside of it, it's undefined.

So, in short, why is `output` undefined?

JavaScript:

```
var output;
var test;
function loadContent() {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var xmlDoc;
    test = "Hello";
    fileReader.readAsText(document.getElementById("slnFile").files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = function (event) {
        output = event.target.result.toString();
        document.getElementById("output").innerText = output.toString();
    };
    alert(output + " | " + test);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theCSS.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>Solution: <input id="slnFile" type="file" onchange="loadContent();"/></p>

        <div id="output"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery_v1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: filereader read functions are async, the onload event hasnt fired yet by the time your alert is executed, so output hasnt been set yet

Comment: wow. i knew i was missing something stupid. THANK YOU

Comment: @PatrickEvans You should change your comment to an answer so it can be accepted.